# Weird Local Connection Error

Tags: networking, lan

[image]

Usually PC 1 & PC 2 can't interact each other because they are using different gateway.

PC 1 is behaving normally, it can ping it's own Gateway (in this case `192.168.3.3`) and got 1ms in return, & can't ping other gateway,

Now PC 2 is weird because it can ping both gateway but got very high latency (about 200ms ~ 400ms).

I already swapped their address (their ethernet cable too of course), it still give same behaviour.

this error make internet connection so slow on PC 2.

I already uninstalled ethernet driver on PC 2 , still no change.

it only happen in PC 2.

Edit : 
- I already tried using Wi-Fi connection too. it's still give same slow response from its gateway.

- I tried using DHCP IP address, it fixed PC 2 problem when connected to Switch A, but when connected to Switch B it stuck in identifying.

Comment: The PCs should be able to communicate. Routers route between networks, and both networks are directly connected to the router. Absent any ACLs or other rules, there should be no problem with either PC pinging the other PC or gateway.

Comment: Is something else saturating your network connection on PC2?

Comment: And thats seems the problem, PC 2 ignoring the rules. Normally 2 gateway can't interact each other in this network

Comment: See switch B's LED on the port connected to PC2. How does it blink? Is there another device connected to switch B?

Comment: there's a few PC on each switch, they don't have this error. I already tried using Wi-fi but the problem still exist.

Comment: After i Uninstall/Reinstall network driver , it works normally for a few second & then its error again